# Angular Shared Navbar Inside The Components Connected To The Module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

In my angular project, I have auth, client and home module. I want to use client module after successfull login. I want to use auth module for login, register and reset password process. Last, I want to use home module for references, home, about us and contact components. However, i can not use my navbar in my home module as shared. I added my navbar to home.component.html file. When i click button, about component html not loading and it only shows navbar. The reason I created 3 modules I want to use lazy loading. Also i want to use different shared navbars before and after login. You can see my module files below. I want home component html to behave like app-component.html. Is this the right approach to use different navbars for different modules? Can you help me ?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HomeModule } from './modules/home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HomeModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      defaultLanguage: 'tr'
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}




import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];
 

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }





import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeNavigationComponent } from './shared/components/home-navigation/home-navigation.component';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "auth", loadChildren: () => import("../auth/auth.module").then(x => x.AuthModule) },
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path:'about', component: AboutComponent
    }
  ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeNavigationComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

.........................................